# PHP conditional echo text instead HTML

Tags: php, html, wordpress, function

I'm trying to create a conditional for a theme in a Wordpress,
If the meta exist show this... else show that.

```
<?php
    $scene_trailer = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'scene_trailer', true);
    if ( $scene_trailer ) {
        echo htmlentities('<div style="width: 645px; height: 364px; overflow: hidden">
            <iframe src="http://tvguide.com/<?php $key="scene_number"; echo get_post_meta($post->ID, $key, true); ?>/" width="645" height="430" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="position: relative; top: -36px"></iframe></div>');
    }
    else {
    echo '<img src="http://i0.tvguide.com/<?php $key="scene_number"; echo get_post_meta($post->ID, $key, true); ?>/576x324.jpg" width="576" height="324" alt="" />';
}
?>
```

My code returns this as plain text:

```
<div style="width: 645px; height: 364px; overflow: hidden"> <iframe src="http://tvguide.com<?php $key="scene_number"; echo get_post_meta($post->ID, $key, true); ?>/" width="645" height="430" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="position: relative; top: -36px"></iframe></div>
```

Can someone please show me what I'm doing wrong? 
Thanks!

Comment: Please update your output in your question for better understanding.

Comment: "My code returns text not HTML" - Please update your output .

Comment: Why do you use `htmlentities` If you want the html code to be displayed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have write wrong php syntax Please try below code.

```
<?php
$scene_trailer = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'scene_trailer', true);
if ($scene_trailer) {
    $key = "scene_number";
    $scene_number = get_post_meta($post->ID, $key, true);
    echo htmlentities('<div style="width: 645px; height: 364px; overflow: hidden">
        <iframe src="http://tvguide.com/' . $scene_number . '" width="645" height="430" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="position: relative; top: -36px"></iframe></div>');
} else {
    echo '<img src="http://i0.tvguide.com/scenes/' . $scene_number . '/576x324.jpg" width="576" height="324" alt="" />';
}
?>
```